# Recurrence relation for the algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I have already given the following algorithm which I have to find the recurrence relation.

```
int Recursive(int n)
{
   if(n<=1)
     return n;
   sum=0;
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      sum++;
   return Recursive(n/2) + Recursive(n/2) + sum;
}
```

I have obtained recurrence relation for the above algorithm as

```
T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + constant
```

But I am not sure about the constant part of this recurrence relation since we have `sum` in the algorithm. Just to clarify, `sum` is a global variable - the lack of declaration is *not* a typo.

Can anyone help me out to get the correct recurrence relation? Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why call `Recursive` recursively twice and add the result? Why not call it once and multiply the result with `2`?

Comment: You are right. But this is actually a exam question.That is why I posted it exactly as it is

Comment: "I posted it exactly as it is "  Seems `;` missing in `sum++`?

Comment: @Rizwan you are not supposed to edit the OP's code. Otherwise comments/answer seems pointless.

Comment: @kiranBiradar - apologies, if that create some problem. However I have just correct the format and added missing semi-colon, that could just be a typo.

Comment: @Rizwan I think same should go as suggestion(comments/answers) apart from the formatting the code.

Comment: @kiranBiradar why not? I find that very appropiate to add whitespaces and the missing `;`. If that would be the error, the question should be closed with *"This question was caused by [...] a simple typographical error."*

Comment: Where is `sum` declared?

Comment: Isn't "recurrence relation" supposed to be a formula for obtaining A[n] given A[n-1] (or A[n/2] in this case) ? And not the time complexity analysis.

Comment: @hellow I assume those modification can be taken as part of answer.

Comment: @NishiShane While it certainly makes the problem much more interesting, is `sum` actually a global variable, or is there a typo in the declaration, i.e. it is a local variable `int sum = 0`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, No its not a typo issue. It just showing as sum=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions made in this answer:

- `sum` is declared globally – since the apparently missing declaration is, as you stated, not a typo.
- The question asks for the return value, not the time complexity.
- The expressions in the return statement are evaluated in their order of appearance; this is not guaranteed by the C standard, so the answer is technically undefined.

---

Note that, since each call does either:

- Returns its argument (if `n <= 1`)
- Resets the value of `sum` to 0

... the function is guaranteed to be "closed", in the sense that its return value will *only* depend on its argument. It follows that:

> The two separate calls to `Recursive(n / 2)` can be combined into just one call, without impacting the return value: `return 2 * Recursive(n / 2) + sum;`.

From this point on-wards is it assumed that this modification has been applied to the original code; this helps in clarifying the flow of the program, since there will now only be one path of execution (instead of branches created by two calls).

---

Now for the key part. The call to `Recursive(n / 2)` *overwrites* the value of `sum` before the function returns, undoing the work done by the preceding `for`-loop. This overwriting behavior continues down the recursion hierarchy, *until* the final call when the stopping condition `n <= 1` is hit (it just returns `n` instead). It follows that:

> There is only **one** value of `sum` which contributes to the final return value, given by its value after the *penultimate* call to `Recursive`.

---

Due to truncation by integer division, when the penultimate call is performed `n` is *always* **2** or **3** (both of which satisfy `n / 2 = 1`); these are thus also the possible final values of `sum`.

What values of `n` give `sum = 2` and `sum = 3` respectively? It is illustrative to consider the binary representation of `n`.

Integer division by 2 is equivalent to shifting the bit-pattern "right" by 1 (or "left" depending on endian-ness...), and discarding the least-significant bit. It follows that the final value of `sum` depends on only the **2** most significant bits of `n`:

```
 initial bit-pattern  >>  penultimate call
 -----------------------------------------
 ...000 10 xxx...         ...0000 10 = 2       
 ...000 11 xxx...         ...0000 11 = 3

 xxx: discarded bits
```

The bit-pattern of `n` has `floor(log2(n)) + 1` significant bits; the final value of `sum` can therefore be compactly expressed as:

> ```
> S(n) = 2 + second_most_significant_bit(n)
> ```

---

How many times is `sum` added to the return value? The number of **recursive** calls to `Recursive`  (i.e. the total number of calls minus one, including the initial call, but excluding the final). This is given by `floor(log2(n))`:

[image]

Note that the return value of the final call will *always* be `1` if initially `n >= 1`. Therefore the final return value of `Recursive` is given by:

> [image]

---

Test C code for confirmation:

```
// override the library definition of log2 to use integers only
int log2(int n) {
   int b = 0;
   while ((n >>= 1) != 0)
      b++;
   return b;
}

// get i-th bit from bit pattern of n
int get_bit(int n, int i) {
   return (n >> (i - 1)) & 1;
}

// calculating return value of Recursive using equation above
int Value(int n) {
   int l2n = log2(n);    // floor(log2(n))
   int p2l = 1 << l2n;   // 2^(floor(log2(n)))
   return p2l + (p2l - 1) * (2 + get_bit(n, l2n));
}
```

Results:

```
n        | Recursive    Value
-------------------------------
2        |  4           4
3        |  5           5
4 - 5    |  10          10
6 - 7    |  13          13
8 - 11   |  22          22
12 - 15  |  29          29
16 - 23  |  46          46
24 - 31  |  61          61
32 - 47  |  94          94
48 - 63  |  125         125
64 - 95  |  190         190
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure about the constant part of this recurrence relation

There is no *constant part*, since `sum` equals `n` after the loop. This gives:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2)+n
```

> So if the sum is global variable, `T(n) = 2T(n/2)+C(Constant)` and if sum is local variable `T(n) = 2T(n/2)+n` . Am I correct?

No, as mch wrote:

> It seems that sum is a global variable… In this case it would be unspecified if `sum` or one of the `Recursive(n/2)` will be evaluated first.

This means it would be *unspecified* whether `T(n) = 2T(n/2)+n` or `T(n) = 2T(n/2)+n/2`; in neither case there's a constant part.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems that `sum` is a global variable, so the latter calls override the value for previous calls. In this case it would be unspecified if `sum` or one of the `Recursive(n/2)` will be evaluated first.

Comment: @mch - Good point - the OP should clarify where `sum` is declared (I'm not sure that the posted code is complete, given the meanwhile corrected error in revision 1).

Comment: @mch, So if the sum is global variable, `T(n) = 2T(n/2)+C(Constant)` and if sum is local variable `T(n) = 2T(n/2)+n` . Am I correct?

Comment: @Nishi Shane - I incorporated your question into my answer.